# Render charts inside Bootstrap (V 3.3.7) modal using React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Am trying to render a chart inside bootstrap modal. The chart has to be rendered only after the modal is shown completely. My requirement is to use Bootstrap with React. I have used react-bootstrap and it works fine. I'm facing the issue with plain Bootstrap.

This is the jQuery code that I have inside componentDidMount(). Here, on click of a button, and when modal is shown, an alert message has to pop up- **which is not happening**. The modal show event is not triggered. This is where I am trying to render my chart. So if the alert message is shown, my chart gets rendered inside a modal.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myBtn").click(function(){
            $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                alert('The modal is fully shown.');
        });
     });
});
```

How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: Using jquery with react or any other framework is not correct. It reduces the performance of react

Comment: is the 'show.bs.modal' event even being triggered. Have you set up an event emitter ? Also remove the $("#myModal").on outside the callbacks. It makes no sense.

Comment: @Prajval M, could you please let me know the right way of doing it?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it without jquery,

You can wait until your chart ( i guess it is an image is completely loaded ). Modal display is only uses css so it will be instantaneous.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state({loaded : false, show : false})
}

imageLoaded(){
    this.setState({loaded : true})
}

btnClick(){
    this.setState({show : true})
}

render(){
    var display = this.state.loaded&&this.state.show ? 'block' : 'none'
    return(
    // All your render
    <ModalDiv style={{display}} >
        <img src={YourSource} onLoad={this.imageLoaded.bind(this)}/>
    </ModalDiv>
    <button onClick={this.btnClick.bind(this)}>YOUR SHOW CHART BUTTON </button>
)}
```

This is a simple variation which will enable you to show the chart only when loaded. You can have multiple variations like record a click event and then show when everything is loaded or use loading screens and all such.

Hope you get it !